# I need to replace 00 with a blank in a pipe delimited file after pipe 5 In Linux

Tags: text-processing, sed

I  need to replace `00` with a blank in a pipe delimited file, but only if the `00` appears after the fifth pipe. I am using Linux. I tried: `{sed 's/00/\ /6' input.txt > output.txt}`

Sample data:

```
FIELD1|FIELD2|FIELD3|FIELD4|FIELD5|FIELD6
ABC|DE|GGH|Y|FFHT|00
ABC|DE|GGH|00|FFHT|Y
ABC|DE|GGH|N|FFHT|N
ABC|DE|GGH|OO|FFHT|
```

I want the following result:

```
FIELD1|FIELD2|FIELD3|FIELD4|FIELD5|FIELD6
ABC|DE|GGH|Y|FFHT|  
ABC|DE|GGH|00|FFHJ|Y
ABC|DE|GGH|N|FFHK|N
ABC|DE|GGH|OO|FFHU|
```

Comment: ```cat sample |sed "s/\(\(.*|\)\{5\}\)00/\1  /"```

Comment: @K-att- please don't post answers as comments.

Comment: Hi, I tried what suggested: sed 's/\(\(.*|\)\{5\}\)00/\1  /' INPUT.txt > OUTPUT.txt, but it did not work for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the example you provided all you need is:

```
$ sed 's/|00$/|/' file
FIELD1|FIELD2|FIELD3|FIELD4|FIELD5|FIELD6
ABC|DE|GGH|Y|FFHT|
ABC|DE|GGH|00|FFHT|Y
ABC|DE|GGH|N|FFHT|N
ABC|DE|GGH|OO|FFHT|
```

or more robustly/flexibly for input of more than 6 fields:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} $6=="00"{$6=""} 1' file
FIELD1|FIELD2|FIELD3|FIELD4|FIELD5|FIELD6
ABC|DE|GGH|Y|FFHT|
ABC|DE|GGH|00|FFHT|Y
ABC|DE|GGH|N|FFHT|N
ABC|DE|GGH|OO|FFHT|
```

Comment: Hi For some reason when I run the awk command file is not getting updated, but when I write to a different file it worked.
I ran the following: 
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} $6=="00"{$6=""} 1' file.txt > file_mod.txt

Comment: Of all the Unix text-processing tools only `ed` updates the input file by default, all of the others write their output to stdout. If you want any other tool to update the input file then check it's man page for a `-i` or `-i inplace` option (which GNU awk has) or do `awk 'script' file.txt > file_mod.txt && mv file_mod.txt file.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -pe 's:pos($/.from)/ \| 00 /| / if m:5th/ \| /;'
```

OR

```perl
raku -pe 's:pos($/.from)[ \| 00 ] = "| " if m:5th[ \| ];'
```

Sample Input:

```
FIELD1|FIELD2|FIELD3|FIELD4|FIELD5|FIELD6
ABC|DE|GGH|Y|FFHT|00
ABC|DE|GGH|00|FFHT|Y
ABC|DE|GGH|N|FFHT|N
ABC|DE|GGH|OO|FFHT|
```

Sample Output:

```
FIELD1|FIELD2|FIELD3|FIELD4|FIELD5|FIELD6
ABC|DE|GGH|Y|FFHT| 
ABC|DE|GGH|00|FFHT|Y
ABC|DE|GGH|N|FFHT|N
ABC|DE|GGH|OO|FFHT|
```

Raku implements an `:nth` "adverb" regex parameter, which allows you to specify which (e.g. `:1st`, `:2nd`, `:nth(5)`) match you're looking for.

The above Raku code combines a match at the `m:5th` position (detecting a `|` vertical bar character) with a `s:pos($/.from)` substitution, which starts searching for a match at the `$/.from` match-variable position.

So if you match the 5th `|`, that position gets saved in `$/.from`. If you find the regex `\| 00` at the `$/.from` position, you substitute with a   blank space. Otherwise the `00` characters remain untouched, as noted after the third `|` on the second data line.

[Note, if you want to leave all "early" columns untouched, and only substitute "later" columns, use the `:continue` adverb instead of the `:pos` adverb].

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#index-entry-matching_adverb_:pos-matching_adverb_:p-Pos
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

`sed "s/\(\(.*|\)\{5\}[^0]*\)00/\1  /" <input.txt`

Means:
`\(\(.*|\)\{5\}` : five slash

`[^0]*` non zeros after fifth slash

all to \1
Print \1 and two zeroes.

Sample input:

```
FIELD1|FIELD2|FIELD3|FIELD4|FIELD5|FIELD6
ABC|DE|GGH|Y|FFHT|rZZ00r
ABC|DE|GGH|00|FFHT|Y
ABC|DE|GGH|N|FFHT|N
ABC|DE|GGH|OO|FFHT|
```

Sample output:

```
FIELD1|FIELD2|FIELD3|FIELD4|FIELD5|FIELD6
ABC|DE|GGH|Y|FFHT|rZZ  r
ABC|DE|GGH|00|FFHT|Y
ABC|DE|GGH|N|FFHT|N
ABC|DE|GGH|OO|FFHT|
```